# How do I exclude an eager loaded query in Polymorphic Relations?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

Lets say this is my table structure:

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text
    reviewed - boolean

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

profileContent
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    content_id - integer
    content_type - string
```

Now I want to receive the contents of the user's profile:

```php
$user->profileContents()
     ->latest()
     ->with(['content' => function ($query){
        //I'm not sure how to do it
     }])
     ->paginate(5);
```

How do I say that IF the column "reviewed" exists it should be true? But it does not matter if videos are reviewed or not.

**Additional Informations:**

profileContents() gives me all the contents of a user profile

```php
public function profileContents()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(ProfileContent::class, Profile::class);
}
```

and with('content') uses to morph to the specific models:

```php
public function content()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Edit 1:**

I'm a bit nearer to my goal. I used a GlobalScope to only show content that is reviewed.

In Post:

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('reviewed', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('reviewed', true);
    });
}
```

But now I have the problem that I still cannot exclude an empty query. I show you the output:

```php
//ProfileContent
array:2 [
  0 => array:8 [
    "id" => 1
    "profile_id" => "1"
    "content_id" => "1"
    "content_type" => "App\Video"
    "content" => "[some array values]"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [
    "id" => 2
    "profile_id" => "1"
    "content_id" => "1"
    "content_type" => "App\Post"
    "content" => null
  ]
]
```

How can I exclude the null array without losing the paginated data (output should be 5)

Answer (score 0):

Review your question one more time u are accessing relationship and then trying to eagerload the relationship again. I am pretty sure this is what you want:

```
$user->contents()
     ->latest()
     ->with(['posts' => function ($query){
      //here you add a query constrain on eagerload like:

        $query->where('reviewed', true);  
     }])
     ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: thank you! I updated my question so it's clearer. Sorry about that. The thing is with $query->where('reviewed', true);  that it does not eager load my videos.